# Text Extraction

Tags: python, regex, bash

```
400   1       2017-06-21T13   rrrrr rrere rrrrr  /var/spool/mail/1    1     fsfgagd    dfgdfgfg
               :01:09.000-07                      495555555_0f102_ke                                          
               :00.                               rnel_topg.0.tar.gz

402   1       2017-06-21T13   rrrrr rrere rrrrr  /var/spool/mail/1    1     fsfgagd    dfgdfgfg
               :01:09.000-07                      495555555_0f102_ke                                          
               :00.                               rnel_topg.0.tar.gz

403   1       2017-06-21T13   rrrrr rrere rrrrr  /var/spool/mail/1    1     fsfgagd    dfgdfgfg
               :01:09.000-07                      495555555_0f102_ke                                          
               :00.                               rnel_topg.0.tar.gz

404   1       2017-06-21T13   rrrrr rrere rrrrr  /var/spool/mail/1    1     fsfgagd    dfgdfgfg
               :01:09.000-07                      495555555_0f102_ke                                          
               :00.                               rnel_topg.0.tar.gz
```

I have an input as shown below. I have 100 such lines as shown above. And every line takes up 3 lines and they are formatted in a table-like pattern. I'm can use bash or python or even both.

This is what I've tried so far

```
 tr -s " " | awk '{print $1 $2 $3}'
```

using Regex: `^\d*(.*)\/var\/spool\/mail\/\d*(.*)`

What i need is a dictionary `{'400':'/var/spool/mail/1495555555_0f102_kernel_topg.0.tar.gz'}`

Comment: Please put more from the input file  and expected out below it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `awk` to solve this

```
# cat file
400   1       2017-06-21T13      /var/spool/mail/1    1
               :01:09.000-07     495555555_0f102_ke
               :00.              rnel_topg.0.tar.gz
500   1       2017-06-21T13      /var/spool/mail/2    1
               :01:09.000-07     495555675_0f102_ke
               :00.              rnel_topf.1.tar.gz
# awk 'BEGIN{i=1}{if(i==1){f1=$1;f2=$4;i++}else if(i==2){f2=f2 $2;i++}else{f2=f2 $2;printf "{'%s','%s'}",f1,f2;print "";i=1}}' file
{400,/var/spool/mail/1495555555_0f102_kernel_topg.0.tar.gz}
{500,/var/spool/mail/2495555675_0f102_kernel_topf.1.tar.gz}
```

Comment: How would you do it if there was a difference of 4 columns between the 2! Like, in this case, its only 2.! what if I had "n" number of columns before reaching the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

If the table/line structure is as strict as you say then you could use a regex like this:

`^(\d+)[^\/]+([^\s]+).+\n[^\-]+-\d+\s+([^\s]+).+\n[^a-z]+([\w.]+)`

This captures your required data in 4 groups (the bits within the brackets) then 'stitches' it together using:

`{'$1':'$2$3$4'}`

to give you the required output of, eg

`{'400':'/var/spool/mail/1495555555_0f102_kernel_topg.0.tar.gz'}`

[Regex101 demo here](https://regex101.com/r/siAHWo/1)

**Breaking down what the regex does:**

`^(\d+)` capture the initial digits at the start of the line

`[^\/]+` skip everything up to the next `/` character

`([^\s]+)` capture everything up to the next space character

`.+\n` match (but don't capture) everything up to the newline

`[^\-]+-\d+\s+` this section is a bit convoluted but I was looking for a 'hook'. It skips everything up to the `-`, then matches digits + spaces

`([^\s]+)` capture everything up to the next space

`.+\n[^a-z]+` match (but don't capture) everything up to the newline, then anything that is not an alpha character in the range `a-z`

`([\w.]+)` capture any word characters (a-z or _) and periods

Again, this will probably only work if the lines are structured as strictly as your examples